# Greasing spacers in cranks

Tags: shimano, crankset, grease

so today I removed my crankset from my bike. Crankset is Shimano SLX and the bike is Canyon Exceed CF 6 2021. It has shimano pressfit bottom bracket.

Whilst putting down the crankset I realised there was grease even on the O-rings. Basically these O-rings are on both sides and they touch the BB shell itself. In the image, you can see there is still a bit of white thing left - that's the grease. It was across the whole ring.
[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is whether I have to grease even that part. When I put down my crankset, there was a lot of grime there consisting of the grease and little stones, dirt etc. I am slightly worried about it all getting inside the BB.

Comment: You grease the shaft because it is steel and can corrode and get stuck if mounted dry. Some grease does escape onto other surfaces but they are not deliberately greased.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is grease on the splines, the BB/spindle contacts (inside the plastic bearing shields the crank rides on), and a thin coating on the spindle. Typically you can get all you need by putting a good layer inside of both bearing shields before passing the spindle through, which is how Shimano BBs come.

Having it anywhere else on a Shimano crank/BB is mostly undesirable, and can attract grime as you say.

Answer (score -1):

get a bottom bracket sleeve kit that will connect to the left and right side BB bearings from inside the bottom bracket shell. the spindle will slide through it. helps to keep alot of dirt from sticking to the spindle and bearings. youll need a Shimano bb30 hollow tech sleeve.